# Paths for 2D Objects in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, path, sprite-kit, cgpath, skaction

So, I am currently making a 1942-style game. How can/should I set up the path for my enemies? I know I could do it with CGPathRef but is there an easier way to do it? It seems pretty out of place for more complex paths like for example these 2 I'd like to implement:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVxAZ.png

(Sorry I can't directly post pictures, I need at least 10 reputation)

Or at least, I haven't found any documentation explaining how to create more complex shapes with CGPaths. 
So what are your recommendations?

Comment: CGPath is as easy as you can get with the current release. If you are looking for other options, try this http://www.paintcodeapp.com

Comment: You could use math too. Your top path on the image is basically a sine wave. The figure 8 is also could be done via math. Also, this is more of a game centric question and you might find this of use : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27513/how-do-you-make-game-objects-enemies-npcs-move-in-interesting-non-linear-way

Comment: I am also making a 1942-ish game and I am thinking of making a pathing class for this type of thing that uses a similar approach to one of the answers on that question - creating multiple motions like arc right or left with a radius. Then you could string together motions to create more complex paths and with variety. I'm also thinking my class will have a way to generate a path via drawing with finger and then outputting the path code to use in the game.

Comment: @prototypical that sounds like a great open source project ;)

Comment: @MikeS I started tonight on it, might github it when I get it working reasonably.

Comment: There is a free app on the Mac app store called motion editor that allows you to draw complex paths using bezier curves. It converts the curves into Objective-C code.